# Ejecutar Stored Procedure Login vb6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

Tengo una app en vb6 que me ha estado dando problemas con la conexion, desde el login hasta consultas basicas, asi que intentare cambiar el login a un stored procedure con la misma consulta que hacia en el codigo

Quedo algo asi

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpLoginQualitz] 
    @Login as nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET nocount ON;
        SELECT Usuarios.Caja ,Usuarios.IdUsuario, CatalogoEmpleados.CodigoEmpleado,usuarios.TipoDeCambio, 
        CatalogoEmpleados.Nombre, Usuarios.Login, Usuarios.Password, 
        CatalogoDepartamentos.Nombre AS Departamento,Usuarios.codigosucursal,Usuarios.supervisor,CatalogoDepartamentos.CorreoElectronico,CatalogoDepartamentos.ClaveCorreoElectronico 
        FROM  CatalogoDepartamentos INNER JOIN 
        CatalogoEmpleados ON CatalogoDepartamentos.CodigoDepartamento = CatalogoEmpleados.CodigoDepartamento RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        Usuarios ON CatalogoEmpleados.CodigoEmpleado = Usuarios.CodigoEmpleado  
        Where login = @Login 
END
```

En Vb6 tenia la idea de como hacerlo pero me atore al momento de regresar un resultado

```
Dim ACommand As New ADODB.Command
    Dim Aprm As New ADODB.Parameter
    Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

    ACommand.ActiveConnection = Cnn
    ACommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    ACommand.CommandText = "SpLoginQualitz"
    Set Aprm = ACommand.CreateParameter("@Login", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, TxtLogin.Text)
    ACommand.Parameters.Append Aprm
    Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    objRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    objRecordset.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    objRecordset.Open ACommand, Cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Hasta ahi me he quedado bloqueado al momento de regresar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos del `recordset` solo tienes que iterar por sus filas y columnas o bien apuntar a columna concreta.

Si esperas que la consulta solo traiga un resultado sería algo así:

```
Dim IdUsuario as integer
if objRecordset.RecordCount > 0 then
        IdUsuario = objRecordset("IdUsuario")
end if
```

Si el procedimiento te devuelve más de una fila, las deberás recorrer.

```
if not objRecordset.eof then
    IdUsuario = objRecordset("IdUsuario "))
    objRecordset.movenext
end if
```